# How to disable Skype extension through selenium webdriver

Tags: java, selenium

Whenever I launch Firefox browser, it opens with Skype enabled. How can I disable it through Selenium & Java?

Comment: I have an idea, which I was on the way to implement for a similar problem, not skype-related however (I wanted to disable a printer). Use firefox to browse to _about:config_ and search for skype. I think it is possible for selenium to set these variables programatically, you'd need to google that.

Comment: What about some details - which OS are you working with; why can't you just install a second firefox without skype; why can't you have a separate test PC or VM instance with firefox without skype; what have you tried so far; etc. ?

Comment: Man, this is one irritating issue. That stupid skype to call extension was driving me nuts. Thanks goodness you posted this.

Answer (score 15):

Here is the solution (I solved this problem in this way):

1. Go to control panel
2. **Uninstall "Skype Click to Call"**
3. Re-run your selenium webdriver test.

**Result:** You will not see Skype window anymore.

Comment: You are awesome bro :) Thanks

Comment: The OP should seriously have select this as the Answer.

Answer (score 0):

I've had this problem as well.  Very frustrating to say the least.  You don't have to solve it via `Selenium`.  Here is what I did.

1. Backup the `Mozilla Firefox` directory where your browser is installed
2. Uninstall `Mozilla Firefox` from `Control Panel/Programs` and features
3. Delete the `Mozilla Firefox` directory which resides in `c:\Program
   Files (x86)`
4. Reinstall `Mozilla Firefox`

When I run my `Firefox Selenium` programs, I no longer get the Skype extension enabled or the intrusive `Skype` extension tab opening up.

I hope this works for you

Answer (score 0):

A simple way is to open Firefox, browse to add-ons tab (type "about:addons" in address bar or use menu "Extra -> Add-ons") and then deactivate or uninstall all unwanted add-ons.

If you use a different profile for Selenium, make sure to change that one.